# Passing data into a separate form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button that when pressed is currently outputting messages to a messagebox. Its not very tidy so I created a new form and placed a text box in there. While the 2nd form picks up the data it presents it in another messagebox rather then the textbox like intended. Help is appreciated.

Form2

```
 public Form2(string strTextBox)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = strTextBox;
    }
```

Form 1

```
 private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            foreach (string error in errorSet)
            {
                Form2 frm = new Form2(error);
                frm.Show();

            }
 }
```

There is some more logic in the button_click if it looks a little strange but its pretty redundant for the problem im having.

Thank you

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You really want it to pop a new `Form2` for every message?  That's click, click, click...for the user.

Comment: Don't do this. Message boxes are there to show messages. If you want to change the image or background of the system/default message box, you can override/create your own. I am not sure what the exact error is as you haven't actually asked a question...

Comment: Sorry. I want the error messages to be placed in a text boxin form2  rather than individual message boxes.

Comment: `"While the 2nd form picks up the data it presents it in another messagebox rather then the textbox like intended."` - That doesn't make a lot of sense given the code shown.  `Form2` doesn't have a `MessageBox`, it just sets the text into a `TextBox`.  In what way is that not working?

Comment: OP should understand what a foreach loop or any loop in general does and what if you had 100 items you really want to see 100 popup messages.. look at using the string.join method and call the MesageBox.Show outside of that loop utilizing the string.Join on a `List<T>` for example

Comment: Similar questions are asked too many times already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop over your errors collection and store them in a StringBuilder, then, show the Form2 only one time outside the loop (if there is at least an error).

Do not forget to make your textbox **MultiLine=true**,  give it enough height and a vertical scroll bar.

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     foreach (string error in errorSet)
        sb.AppendLine(error);

    if(sb.Lenght> 0)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2(sb.ToString());
        frm.Show();
    } 
}
```

Comment: That works well thank you but why is it creating so many textbox's and not just one?

Comment: Your previous code creates a new instance of Form2 at every loop. So if you have 10 errors, your code creates 10 forms (`Form2 frm = new Form2()`) and each form has its own textbox where a single error message will be printed